# Replacing UINavigationController with UITabController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

This is a real beginners thing I know but I'm just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

I'm going through the great Ray Wenderlich series about Table Views, here's the last one

http://www.raywenderlich.com/68139/video-tutorial-table-views-search

However I want to create an app that is similar to those examples but also has a TabViewController, so I created a new TabViewController in the storyboard, and then created a segue between that and the UITableViewController, and it runs fine until I tap on one of the cells in the table view to bring on the next view controller, then I get this error...

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'GoToEdit'.
>   Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by
>   an instance of UINavigationController.'

I don't get this error because all I've done is remove the original segue to the original view controller, and replaced it with a TabViewController and then linked them up with a new segue.

[image]

Comment: Your tab should attached to navigation controller, and navigation controller will go to table view controller. As of now, navcontroller is missing inbetween tab and table controllers.

Comment: Refer: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: I just tried a segue between the tab controller and the original uinavcontroller and then from that to the table view controller but it didn't work, all I get is a no item tab view controller displayed and a black screen above

Comment: Have you referred the link which I posted, it has the same scenario and with explanation. Topic name in that: "Adding a Table View Controller"

Comment: I just downloaded the example code, and compiled and it doesn't work properly, I get this warning "/Test/Ratings/Ratings/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: warning: Unsupported Configuration: Scene is unreachable due to lack of entry points and does not have an identifier for runtime access via -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:.
"

Answer (score 0):

You should embede in NavigationController your **Pretty Icons Scene**. Thats all.

Comment: I embedded the Nav controller inside the Tab controller and it works fine but I don't understand how? why did it not work when I created a nav controller and then did a segue to the nav controller? what's the difference?

Comment: According to screenshot you attached, u tried to push segue not from navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

Click on Main.storyboard then select tabbar controller and then click Editor -> Embede In -> Navigation Controller

Comment: The Navigation Controller is greyed out.